# Problem importing LilyPond .pdf to PiaScore

Tags: pdf, lilypond

I have a problem related to the compatibility between .pdf files generated from  LilyPond .ly files and the .pdf files used in a iPad/iPhone application PiaScore, which is used by some of the performers I work with.

When I import in the PiaScore iPad app  a .pdf file generated from a LilyPond .ly source file, the engraving boxes appear in a blue color. I attached an image showing the problem.

[pdf generated from ly source imported in PiaScore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5NPg.png)

To compile the .ly file to .pdf I have used the following:
a) command-line,
version: LilyPond 2.25.2

lilypond --pdf name.ly

b) Frescobaldi,

c) TeXShop.

The same result occurs with any of those.

Is there a way I can solve this problem?
Is there a way to hide the color boxes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds to me like the problem is in PiaScore rather than the PDF file, though without having the PDF file I can't really tell. Its better to post the PDF rather than a picture of the PDF, though it does help identify the problem. Have you tried opening the PDF in any other application, eg Acrobat ? If the blue boxes don't appear there, then it seems likely the problem is in PiaScore.

Comment: Thanks KenS. It only occurs with PiaScore, and no with other pdf readers such as Acrobat. I tried to solve the problem  adding \override Score.NonMusicalPaperColumn #'transparent = ##t in the \score block in LilyPond. But that made invisible other texts, such as titles or subtitles. Finally I found some help in another app: "forScore". They proposed to open Tools menu /Settings/Pdf annotations and uncheck hyperlinks . That solved the problem.